# How to get a VirtualBox W7 application out of the headless mode while running?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, virtualbox, cmd

I got a little project where i try to get an old driver back to work. The problem of the driver is that it only works on 32 bit. Like most os's today are 64 bit(W7). This will give a problem. First I tried to solve this problem with windows virtual (xp mode). This way worked well but the usb device that had to connect gave some problems sometimes, so i went to another virtualization softwear "VirtualBox" with this program its easyer and more options to do the thing i want to do. I already found the code how to attach a usb device this was pretty easy. but now i want to start up the virtual os (Windows 7 32bit) in a **headless** mode and run an GUI to communicate with the old device (the driver). You can start up your os system in headless mode with this code:

```
VBoxManage startvm VM_NAME -type vrdp
```

After a while you can hear the startup sound and then you can start applications with this code:

```
vboxmanage guestcontrol test exec "C:\Windows\System32\SnippingTool.exe" --username test --password f
```

If you get the VERR_UNRESOLVED_ERROR this means your password or username is wrong.

After you start the application, the application will run in headless mode. So you wont see the window of the application. Its more like a background application.

I want this application to be visible. I know there is a **seamless** mode but this seamless mode still gives you the taskbar of the guest os. This can be confusing for non advanced users. I also tried to auto hide the task bar and setting the pop up time to the highest time possible but it was too unstable (I tried it with taskbar activate).

Does mybe any one of you guys know a command to get the application out of headless mode without showing the Taskbar? Or a way to remove the taskbar in seamless mode?

Thx

Comment: Have you considered splitting your application into two parts, a back end running on the virtual machine and a front end running on the host?

Comment: The program isnt mine so i cant change the code...

Comment: Not really a programming question, then, should probably be moved to superuser.

Comment: Oh there is a second forum, mybad! I'm new so... But I maybe found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reboot the OS to get it out of headless mode, it looks like VirtualBox doesnt load all serveries. But I found an easy solution to remove the Taskbar, just kill explorer and your one program still will work and the taskbar will be gone.